# Unreal: Diagnosing why Windows cannot load a DLL

Tags: windows, dll, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to set up a Windows Server-based continuous integration server to completely build and package an Unreal Engine 4 project. The vast majority of the process works, but at the content cooking stage I keep running into the following errors:

```
********** COOK COMMAND STARTED **********
Running UE4Editor Cook for project C:\workspace\CEIT_ingame-native-plugins_PR-44\sampleProjects\unreal\ShooterGame26\ShooterGame.uproject
Commandlet log file is C:\Unreal426\Windows\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Cook-2021.07.05-13.56.23.txt
Running: C:\Unreal426\Windows\Engine\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-Cmd.exe C:\workspace\CEIT_ingame-native-plugins_PR-44\sampleProjects\unreal\ShooterGame26\ShooterGame.uproject -run=Cook  -TargetPlatform=WindowsClient -fileopenlog -ddc=DerivedDataBackendGraph -unversioned -abslog=C:\Unreal426\Windows\Engine\Programs\AutomationTool\Saved\Cook-2021.07.05-13.56.23.txt -stdout -CrashForUAT -unattended -NoLogTimes  -UTF8Output
  LogInit: Display: Running engine for game: ShooterGame
  LogModuleManager: Warning: ModuleManager: Unable to load module 'C:/Unreal426/Windows/Engine/Binaries/Win64/UE4Editor-OpenGLDrv.dll' because the file couldn't be loaded by the OS.
  LogModuleManager: Warning: ModuleManager: Unable to load module 'C:/Unreal426/Windows/Engine/Plugins/Lumin/MagicLeap/Binaries/Win64/UE4Editor-MagicLeap.dll' because the file couldn't be loaded by the OS.
Took 14.257796s to run UE4Editor-Cmd.exe, ExitCode=1
ERROR: Cook failed.
       (see C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Unreal426+Windows\Log.txt for full exception trace)
AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=25 (Error_UnknownCookFailure)
BUILD FAILED
```

Specifically, `UE4Editor-OpenGLDrv.dll` and `UE4Editor-MagicLeap.dll` cannot be loaded, but there's not any clear indication as to why this is, just that "the file couldn't be loaded by the OS". The log files written to disk don't tell me much more than the information above. I've verified that both DLLs are actually present on the CI server, so I suspect that there is some other sub-dependency missing.

I've tried running [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) on the Unreal executable and the DLLs mentioned in the logs to work out which DLLs might be missing on the server machine itself, but this takes over three hours to run to completion, so is a bit awkward and time-consuming to do repeatedly. I've followed the advice regarding missing dependencies from [this page](https://adamrehn.com/articles/building-docker-images-for-unreal-engine-4/), and have gone through all of the likely DLLs that were reported as not found by the Dependencies utility (mostly DirectX/OpenGL related ones), but the build still fails and I'm running out of ideas.

Is there any easy way in Windows to work out exactly why a DLL fails to load? I seem to remember that Windows DLL loading error messages are nowhere near as informative as on Linux, but perhaps there's a tool or an easier method to work it out that I'm not familiar with.

---

EDIT: I've narrowed things down somewhat - if I attempt to load `glu32.dll` completely dynamically in a program of my own, I get the load error `Could not load C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll: The specified procedure could not be found.` As this is on the load attempt, rather than attempt at looking up a function, it implies that some procedure is missing on a sub-dependency of `glu32.dll`, but I don't know how I'd go about identifying which one it is.

Comment: According to the source code, you can run the commandline with -dllerrors and that will open a window with the error. See FWindowsPlatformProcess::GetDllHandle.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a good shout. I'll give it a go and see.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems -dllerrors has no effect on the output of the build program.

Comment: Could it be a *32bit* - *64bit* mismatch? The output is not at all clear. It should contain the underlying *Win* error (code).

Comment: The only exit code I get is `1`, though it used to be `FFFFFFFFC0000135` before I added some DLLs to the CI server that were present on my desktop machine. I have made sure that I've copied both 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs to the server.

Comment: I've just realised that, according to https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/why-do-64-bit-dlls-go-system32-and-32-bit-dlls-syswow64-64-bit-windows, System32 is for 64-bit DLLs and SysWOW64 is for 32-bit DLLs. That's not what I assumed when I copied the dependencies to the CI system, so I'll try the other way around. Thanks, Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete Engine/Intermediate and click GenerateProjectFiles.bat to regenerate the whole project if you use UE Source code to start up, see [UE documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/BuildingUnrealEngine/) and rebuild with Visual Studio.
If you use the UE4-Editor to start up lacking dll, just add dependency within YourProject.build.cs like a third party, see [UE document](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/BuildTools/UnrealBuildTool/ThirdPartyLibraries/).