# Windows DLL function behaviour is different if DLL is moved to different location

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I'm attempting to debug some very opaque issues with DLLs in Unreal on a CI machine (see [Unreal: Diagnosing why Windows cannot load a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68258600/unreal-diagnosing-why-windows-cannot-load-a-dll) for more information). `glu32.dll` seems to be the DLL at which the Unreal process falls over, and as Windows Server doesn't contain all the graphics-related DLLs that normal Windows 10 does, I was recommended to upload certain DLLs from my machine/Microsoft redistributables in order to make sure the Unreal build process could run.

For sanity purposes, I've written a small utility program to test whether `glu32.dll` on my machine can be dynamically loaded and can have its functions called correctly. I'm planning to run this executable on the troublesome CI machine soon to see what happens.

The code for the program is below:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/gl.h>

extern "C"
{
    typedef const GLubyte* (__stdcall *ErrorStringFunc)(GLenum error);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: GLU32Loader.exe <path to glu32.dll>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    const char* path = argv[1];
    std::cout << "Attempting to load: " << path << std::endl;

    HMODULE dllHandle = LoadLibraryA(path);

    if (!dllHandle)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not load " << path << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Successfully loaded DLL: 0x" << dllHandle << std::endl;

    const char* funcName = "gluErrorString";

    std::cout << "Looking up function: " << funcName << std::endl;
    ErrorStringFunc func = reinterpret_cast<ErrorStringFunc>(GetProcAddress(dllHandle, funcName));

    if (func)
    {
        std::cout << "Successfully loaded function: 0x" << func << std::endl;

        const GLubyte* str = (*func)(100902);
        std::cout << "Error string for value 100902: \"" << str << "\" (0x" << static_cast<const void*>(str) << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load function " << funcName << std::endl;
    }

    FreeLibrary(dllHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the executable and point it to `glu32.dll` in the `System32` folder, I get expected output:

```
> GLU32Loader.exe "C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll"
Attempting to load: C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll
Successfully loaded DLL: 0x00007FFC7A350000
Looking up function: gluErrorString
Successfully loaded function: 0x00007FFC7A35C650
Error string for value 100902: "out of memory" (0x000001E5757F51D0)
```

However, if I copy the DLL to my desktop and run the program again, although the DLL and function appear to be loaded, the string returned from the function is empty:

```
> GLU32Loader.exe "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\glu32.dll"
Attempting to load: C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\glu32.dll
Successfully loaded DLL: 0x00007FFC8DDB0000
Looking up function: gluErrorString
Successfully loaded function: 0x00007FFC8DDBC650
Error string for value 100902: "" (0x0000025C5236E520)
```

Why would this be? It's exactly the same DLL, just in a different folder, and I would have thought that any other dependent DLLs that it references should still be available because they're all in `System32`. Is there some mystical property of Windows DLLs that I'm not familiar with that might cause this to happen?

Comment: That is a weirdly specific issue, I'd use a debugger to step into gluErrorString in both cases and see what's the difference in what's going on

Comment: The debugger doesn't actually let me see the contents of gluErrorString. I dunno whether this is because PDBs for it aren't available on my machine, or because I linked to it completely dynamically.

Comment: You could also use Process Monitor to see if there is any difference in which files are accessed when you run it.

Comment: Debugger: if you set a breakpoint in your code and then "step into" the function call it should work, you should get the disassembled code of glu32 and be able to single-step through it too - not the source of course but assembly

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't even seem to let me step into the assembly...

Comment: Not sure why that is (maybe there is a setting you need to enable) but I think I solved the mystery - potentially. Can you tell me whether the file on your desktop is also called `glu32.dll` or you gave it a different name like `glu32_test.dll` or whatever? Because it seems in `gluErrorString` there is a part that calls `GetModuleHandle("glu32.dll")` (instead of saving the `hInstance` in `DllMain` and using that - Microsoft, pls) and later uses the handle to load the strings from resources with `LoadString`, and that would mess things up because it'd return `NULL` if you renamed the DLL.

Comment: Hm damn that's not it, I just realized in the output that you copied, it's still called `glu32.dll`. D:

Comment: The underlying mechanics make a lot of sense, though. I'm wondering whether LoadString is involved in this somehow, just perhaps not in the exact way you described. If GetModuleHandle("glu32.dll") is called, I take it this would load the glu32.dll from System32 rather than the desktop one I'm using?

Comment: No because it gets the handle to an _already loaded_ module. The other thing would be `LoadLibrary`. But it's also possible that this is called elsewhere, and I'm not sure what `GetModuleHandle` will do if there are two modules with the same name loaded. You could try what happens if you temporarily rename the DLL in system32 so it can't be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of why one shall not mess around with system DLLs.

The DLL in question, like many Microsoft DLLs, uses [MUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/multilingual-user-interface) (Multilingual User Interface).

If you look at its resources, it has no resources except a MUI type resource, pointing to a folder containing the corresponding `.mui` file, which contains its actual (internationalized) resources.

So, if you still want to copy it, at least also copy the corresponding `.mui` file:

- `System32\glu32.dll` → `<my_files>\glu32.dll`
- `System32\en-US\glu32.dll.mui` → `<my_files>\en-US\glu32.dll.mui`

The `en-US` part may be different on your system depending on the default locale.

Comment: That's almost certainly the issue. I'll test it out on my machine and approve this answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Ah shoot, MUI, I forgot about that. You are right. So, with the missing MUI file, the behavior of `LoadString` returning `0` and `glu32` not handling this as error but as zero-length string instead would also be as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I saw only now from your log that you *didn't* rename the file. Then I'm not sure what it can be. I'll leave this explanation up anyway because it would also be what happens if one were to rename that file, so maybe it is helpful to someone else...

---

It seems to me as if you **renamed the DLL file** (not just loaded it from another location but with another filename as well).

`glu32.dll` doesn't like to be renamed, because in some places code like `GetModuleHandle("glu32.dll")` is used instead of saving the `hInstance` received in `DllMain` into a global variable and using that handle (which is what *should* have been done, but unfortunately it isn't what Microsoft did). If you rename the DLL, this call will return `NULL`. Now unfortunately there also isn't much error handling going on in `glu32` in that case.

The error strings are stored in global arrays of some sort, but they are lazy-loaded there from string table resources. The first time you call `gluErrorString`, the error strings are loaded using `LoadString` which takes the `hInstance` of the DLL. With the renamed DLL, this will be the bogus `NULL` handle, and calling `LoadString(NULL, ...)` will return `0`, indicating an error. Normally the number returned is the length of the string. `glu32` doesn't handle the zero case in any special way and just copies the zero characters to the array and happily returns an empty string to you at the end.